# Setting the value of a boolean XMLElement

Tags: development, infopath, xml, elements-xml

I'm having a problem when assigning a value to a Boolean check/tick box within InfoPath xml code. I've created text boxes using inner text values but this gives the error of an incorrect data type. How do you set up a standard check box to a value of true using XmlElement?

Here's the code I attempted to use:

```
{...
 {...

 XmlElement elShowResult = xDoc.CreateElement("my", "ShowResult", NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my"));
 elShowResult.InnerText = "TRUE";

 elNewOrganismDetail.AppendChild(elNewTestResult);

 }
}
//attach the organism entry
//ERROR: Schema validation found non-data type errors.
xpOrganismResultData.AppendChild(elNewOrganismDetail.CreateNavigator());
```

> ERROR: InvalidOperationException; Schema validation found non-data type errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XmlElement elShowResult = xDoc.CreateElement("my", "ShowResult", NamespaceManager.LookupNamespace("my"));
elNewTestResult.AppendChild(elShowResult);
elNewTestResult.InnerText = "true";
```

Comment: did you mean **elShowResult**.InnerText = "true"; either way seems to throw the same error, fyi added above